# Regarding Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push

I have few questions regarding Push Notification.

1) If an app is live on AppStore with out push notification and I want to update a new binary with Push Notification enabled in it. Is it possible to enable push notification in updated build if it is not in previous released build? If Yes How and if No Why?

2) If answer to 1st question is No then Is it possible that In my first release build If I enable push notification to Apple ID and do actual coding etc in 2nd Updated build?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible, you will have to enable push notifications for your App ID, make binary with updated provisioning, and then submit.

Comment: Thanks Waheeda, So Its means that push notification can be provided in updated binary whether it is not present in earlier release and apple just see bundle id and it should be same in previous and new updated binary.

Answer (score 0):

yes u have to make new binary with push notification code and with push notification enabled provisioning profile and then submit this code with new version.

U can use urban airship or apple's push notification.